# NextJS url not working after getting exported

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I just started using Next JS, following [Brad Traversy's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTz0GXj8NN0) on youtube. I used `next export` to export the program, just like he did in his tutorial. I used `serve -s out -p 8000`. The page loads on `localhost:8000`, however when I go to other links like `localhost:8000/about`, it just reloads the home page.

I looked for solutions online, I tried adding `"trailingSlash": true` to my `next.config.js` file, and it still doesn't work.

And the most confusing part is when clicked on a Link element (from the "next/link" module) on the page, *it works*, and it takes me to the correct page. But when I want to access it directly from the address bar *it doesn't work*.

Btw it also works during production.

**Edit**

Here is the `next.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
    trailingSlash: true,
};
```

Here is the `package.json` file:

```json
{
    "name": "next-cc",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "export": "next build && next export"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "next": "10.1.3",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2"
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Here is the folder structure

[image: Folder Structure]

Here is a [link](https://github.com/navy87/nextjs-tutorial) to the project

Comment: Can you access the About page by adding `.html` to the end of the URL: `localhost:8000/about.html`?

Comment: @juliomalves but no i can't do that either

Comment: Can you post your full `next.config.js` please?

Comment: @juliomalves okay. I just added it

Comment: @juliomalves Here is a [link](https://github.com/navy87/nextjs-tutorial) to the project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is not with Next.js or the export, but rather with the command you're running to serve the static files.

Using the `-s` option in the `serve` command will rewrite all files to `index.html`. Simply run the command without that option.

```sh
npx serve out -p 8000
```

Comment: That works for `serve` command, but you copy the *out* folder to Nginx, it still won't work like create-react-app does.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same issue with a complete static site I wanted to export. Unfortunately the proposed answer did not work for me, because I was deploying the site to an apache instance.

Next export basically renders the site pages with html extensions, so next/link tags to your `/about` page will still work when clicked, but not when called via your browser url.

To overcome this you need to make use of the `exportPathMap` entry in your `next.config.js` ([exportPathMap](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap) in documentation)

```
exportPathMap: async function (
    defaultPathMap,
    { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
  ) {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' },
      '/about': { page: '/about' },
      '/about/index': { page: '/about' },
    }
  },
```

Usually Next uses the pages directory and exports static files with the page name and appends .html to them - so http://localhost:3000/about becomes http://example.com/about.html - but if you still want the short urls you can add an `/about/index` entry in your path map, which will generate an `index.html` file in an `about` directory, which will then still have your short `/about` link working as expected on your live server, even on page reloads or by entering the url in browser directly.

Comment: In Nginx, it also has the issue, this answer works. However, it appends an ugly trailing slash automatically, (by accessing `/about` you get `/about/`).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, simply the nextJS after the export does not work other routes,

What I did to solve it was to implement a react-router-dom in my index.tsx

I followed this tutorial here

https://colinhacks.com/essays/building-a-spa-with-nextjs

Don't delete the pages folder, it still needs to be there, all my routes worked after that.

But for dynamic routes, dont use nextJS router.query, it will go be undefined, because loads to fast, use this...

Or any split to get the part /:id of your url param.

```
const path = window.location.pathname
const parts = path.split('/')
const id = parts[parts.length - 2]
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](/help/deleted-answers).